# How to get notified when session is about to expire? Spring-boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-session

I've tried using

```
public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event)
{


  if(event instanceof SessionDestroyedEvent){
```

and

```
 @WebListener
 public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

      @Override                                                                                                                                                                                                   
     public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
```

First one, I didn't get `SessionDestoryedEvent` event at all.

It seems spring might notify us after session is expired.
Is there a reliable way to get notified *`before`* session is expired?

Preferably I want solution without `spring-session` package.

I'm not getting `sessionDestroyed` nor `sessionCreated` with the following code..

```
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;
 import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

 @WebListener
 public class MySessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

   private static int totalActiveSessions;

   public static int getTotalActiveSession(){
     return totalActiveSessions;
   }

   public MySessionListener()
   {
     System.out.println("MySessionListener -------------");

   }
   @Override                                                                                                                                                                         
 public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent arg0) {
   totalActiveSessions++;                                                                                                                                                            
 System.out.println("sessionCreated - add one session into counter");                                                                                                              

}

@Override                                                                                                                                                                         
 public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent arg0) {
   totalActiveSessions--;
   System.out.println("sessionDestroyed - deduct one session from counter");
   }
 }
```

Comment: Which session store are you using with Spring Session?

Comment: @VedranPavić I'm using jdbc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Session JDBC does not support publishing of session events due to the obvious limitations of an underlying data store in that regard. A relational database, by itself, has no pub-sub like mechanism that could be used to propagate events to all nodes in the cluster.

This is documented both in the [reference manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/#api-jdbcoperationssessionrepository) and the [`JdbcOperationsSessionRepository` javadoc](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/master/spring-session-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/jdbc/JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.java#L62-L64).

Regarding the second part of your question, with session stores that support event publishing (such as Redis and Hazelcast) Spring Session translates all the events it publishes to standard Servlet API's `HttpSessionEvent` instances. While you could listen to [Spring Session's event hierarchy](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/api/org/springframework/session/events/AbstractSessionEvent.html) is recommended to keep all session related interactions through standard Servlet API mechanisms.

Session events related to expiration/deletion are published when session is to be invalidated, as per [`HttpSession`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) and [`HttpSessionListener#sessionDestroyed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html#sessionDestroyed(javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent)). I'm not sure what exactly do you mean by getting notified *before* session is expired, as it a vague term that depends on your expectations of how much *before*.

Comment: Thanks for authorative answer, I'd like to remove session from the db when it's about to expire. (because another server is looking at the db if the session is alive or not)

Comment: I'm not getting ` HttpSessionListener#sessionDestroyed` or `sessionCreated` . I know my class's constructor gets called.

Comment: `JdbcOperationsSessionRepository` takes care of removal of expired sessions automatically ([see here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/master/spring-session-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/jdbc/JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.java#L524-L533)), are you trying to say that doesn't work for you? Regarding `HttpSessionListener`, it doesn't get invoked since Spring Session JDBC does not support publishing of session events, as explained in the answer. You need to use Spring Session with session store that support event publishing, such as Redis or Hazelcast.